# (VS2012, C#) How to create an amount of customly designed elements and scroll them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

1 element essentially consists of 2 pictureboxes left and right and a label/text in between. They are supposed to be an inseparable unit. (person image and their name, status color right)

I want to put several of those elements in a scrollable box.

My current solution is a bit perverted: I created 5  of my desired elements by myself and change their content on mousewheel scroll and a "fake" scroll bar consisting of a bar image with a scroll position box overlay that changes position dependent on whats displayed. This obviously is a disgusting solution I don't want to keep.

Project language is C#, it's an office addin written in VS Ultimate 2012.

It's a custom one click call solution for my company that draws it's source data directly from outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a UserControl and added them as needed to a FlowLayoutPanel when I had similiar requirements. Of course that's using WinForms, and WPF might work better for you.

Comment: I am not sure what the difference between WinForms and Windows Presentation Foundation is. Til now I just used the VS Designer elements for GUIs.

Comment: I found the solution by googling "creating custom usercontrol visual studio". Thanks. This is it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttb1w24s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is making an custom class that derives from Panel, give it 2 pictureboxes and a label as properties or as constructor parameters, add them to the Panel (this.Add(), since the class is the panel), set their position etc. and add your custom panel to your scrollable box.

Comment: That sounds somewhat sensible and I will try it out. THough what do you mean with scrollable box? Which scrollable box element shall I feed my custom panels to?

Comment: Should I just manually create a class and extend or choose a special visual c# item like "Windows Form"?